# how to make these even elements append to this two dimensional array 5x5

Tags: python

How to make these even elements append to this two dimensional 5 elements per each
array and numbers gradually evenly increasing each array not repeating themselves
each array.

```
multiarray = [[], [], [], [], []]
for i in range(2,150,2):
    for indexRow in range(len(multiarray)):
        multiarray[indexRow].append(i)
    i = i + 1
    if len(multiarray[0]) >= 5:
        break
print(multiarray)
```

Comment: What should your out put look like? Never overestimate your prose ;-)

Comment: `[[2, 4, 6, 8, 10], [12, 14, 16, 18, 20] `etc @user2390182

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following simplification will work:

```
multiarray = [[], [], [], [], []]

i = iter(range(2, 150, 2))

for array in multiarray:
    for _ in range(5):
        array.append(next(i))
```

The whole thing can of course be brought to one line:

```
multiarray = [list(range(2*5*i+2, 2*5*(i+1)+2, 2)) for i in range(5)]
```

Another hint: use `itertools.count` to produce an infinite amount of regular numbers lazily:

```
from itertools import count

# i = iter(range(2, 150, 2))
i = count(2, step=2)
```

Comment: Cant i do it without next function?

Comment: See the comprehension one-liner.  Your data is so regular, you just have to get the math right. I am sure one can do it even simpler.